# Pygame : Why does the music volume decrease when playing a sound?

Tags: python, pygame

When I do sound.play(), the volume of the music in background is reduced. How can I fix this ?

Here is my code:

```py
import pygame
import time


pygame.mixer.pre_init(44100, -16, 2, 1024)
pygame.mixer.init()

jump1 = pygame.mixer.Sound("sounds\\jump\\jump01.wav")
pygame.mixer.music.load("sounds\\music\\theme.wav")

pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)
time.sleep(3)
jump1.play()

input()
```

After 3 seconds the sound "jump01" is played and the music becomes quieter. I would like the music volume not to get changed. After it looks like the music becomes slowly louder.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Does jump01 naturally get quieter? Are you sure this is a coding problem?

Comment: jump01 is an very short sound I couldn't tell, I'll try to see. I think yes, the music file in it's own, doesn't become quieter.

Answer (score 0):

well i'm not sure if this will help you, but you might want to try the way I have may sounds played`

```
jump_sound = pygame.mixer.Sound('jump.wav')`
grass_sounds = [pygame.mixer.Sound('grass_0.wav'), pygame.mixer.Sound('grass_1.wav')]
grass_sounds[1].set_volume(0.2)
grass_sounds[0].set_volume(0.2)
pygame.mixer.music.load('music.wav')
pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)
```

you can change the volume like this:
grass.sounds[0].set_volume(5.5)

this works for me and the sounds don't have any trouble playing

Comment: sorry it's grass_sounds not grass.sounds